# How to divide a string into 2 parts of before and after digit using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, substring

I need to find the first occurrence of a number in a string and fetch the text string before that number using XSLT
Forex: Fazantstraat 22 is the string i need to only string Fazantstraat 
,abcdefg 1234 so i need abcdefg etc

Comment: can you use xsl 2.0?

Comment: why should I reopen this? I can see no improvement at all. can only hint for the documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
<input>Fazantstraat 22</input>
```

the following instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(translate(input, '123456789', '000000000'), '0')"/>
```

will return:

```
Fazantstraat
```

(with a trailing space). That's for XSLT 1.0.

in XSLT 2.0, you can use regex:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(input, '\d.*', '')"/>
```

---

### Added:

If you want to split the input into two separate elements, it would be better to use the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction (in XSLT 2.0), e.g:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="input" regex="\d.*">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <number>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </number>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <address>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </address>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9e/1

Comment: thanks, a lot for the response, i can use xsl 2.0 and this helps me, need one more help from same input string i provided I need to send another field as with starting numbers, for ex Fazantstraat 22abc so i need to send 22abc, can you please suggest?

Comment: @BharatiKharat See the addition to my answer.

Comment: This helps too ,thanks a lot for great help

Comment: Thanks Michael demo and above code helped alot !!